# How to display the highest and lowest points on the drawn graph?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts, drawing

I have a page that has a drawable space and the user needs to draw a graph there. When the chart is drawn, I need to display the points at the highest and lowest value of the graph.

For example, the user drew a graph:
[image]

After that, need to display the points:
[image]

How to implement this, can someone come across a similar one and there are special libraries? The project is written in React

Answer (score 1):

From mathematical point of view, you have to:

- determine function of this graph
- make a derivative of that function
- each time when derivative function touch x axis (y=0) you have local maximum or minimum

But there is a simpler way.

You can check each point and:

- if previous point is less than current and next is also less then you have local maximum
- if previous point is greater than current and next is also greater then you have local minimum

You can compare more that one previous or next point to have more precise results